# What is the right way to model prepositional relationships in a graph database? (e.g., A does B on C, X buys Y through Z)

Tags: graph-databases

Let's say I wanted to have a database of shoppers, grocery stores, and produce. For example, Billy's Grocery supplies carrots and turnips. Alice's Grocery supplies carrots and radishes. Jinh buys carrots from Alice's Grocery, and she buys turnips from Billy's Grocery.

It would seem like "carrot", "Jinh", and "Alice's Grocery" would be three nodes. I know about hyperedges, but from what I've read, they have performance issues. It seems like an anti-pattern to encode one of those nodes as a relationship (for example, a relationship "buys_carrots_from").

Is there a sensible way to represent that relationship (Jinh buys carrots from Alice's Grocery)? Or does this type of data not translate well over graph databases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With only (:grocery), (:product) and (:consumer) nodes

```
create (Billy_s:grocery{name:"Billy's"})
create (Alice_s:grocery{name:"Alice's"})
create (carrots:product)
create (turnips:product)
create (radishes:product)
create (Jinh:consumer)
```

you cannot model this correctly as a graph. (I know my code is only pseudo code) `create (Jinh)-[BUYS]->(carrots)` only indicates Jinh potentially buys carrots from Alice's.

So we need an intermediary, and as usual, this intermediary is useful to store some more information: the price

```
create (Billy_s_carrots:offer{price:0.45})
create (Billy_s_turnips:offer{price:1.12})
create (Alice_s_carrots:offer{price:0.42})
create (Alice_s_radises:offer{price:1.50})

create (Billy_s)-[:SUPPLIES]->(Billy_s_carrots)-[:WHICH_ARE]->(carrots)
create (Billy_s)-[:SUPPLIES]->(Billy_s_turnips)-[:WHICH_ARE]->->(turnips)
create (Alice_s)-[SUPPLIES]->(Alice_s_carrots)-[:WHICH_ARE]->(carrots)
create (Alice_s)-[SUPPLIES]->(Alice_s_radishes)-[:WHICH_ARE]->(radishes)
```

Now if

```
create (Jinh)-[:DESIRES]->(carrots) // and
create (Jinh)-[:DESIRES]->(turnips)
```

He/she has the choice to save money

```
create (Jinh)-[:BUYS]->(Alice_s_carrots) // and
create (Jinh)-[:BUYS]->(Billy_s_turnips)
```

or to save time

```
create (Jinh)-[:BUYS]->(Billy_s_carrots) // and
create (Jinh)-[:BUYS]->(Billy_s_turnips)
```

Comment: With Graph databases, you get rid of binary connection tables, but not of n-ary ones.

Answer (score 0):

This question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61395285/graphdb-node-as-a-property-of-a-relationship/61437078#61437078). So I am trying to answer it following the same logic.

An alternative is to represent "Alice" from "Jinh bought carrots from Alice's Grocery" as a property of "bought". The data model is:

[image]

For illustration purpose, the following queries are in nGQL, the graph query language developed by Nebula Graph.

```
// define the schema
create tag person(name string)
create tag produce(name string)
create tag store(name string)
create edge bought(store string)
create edge supply(price double)

// insert the vertex
INSERT VERTEX person(name) VALUES 100:("Jinh");
INSERT VERTEX produce(name) VALUES 200:("carrot");
INSERT VERTEX produce(name) VALUES 201:("turnips");
INSERT VERTEX produce(name) VALUES 202:("radishe");
INSERT VERTEX store(name) VALUES 300:("Alice's");
INSERT VERTEX store(name) VALUES 301:("Bill's");


// insert the edge
INSERT EDGE bought(store) VALUES 100->200:("Alice's");
INSERT EDGE bought(store) VALUES 100->201:("Bill's");
INSERT EDGE supply(price) VALUES 300->200:(0.42);
INSERT EDGE supply(price) VALUES 300->202:(1.5);
INSERT EDGE supply(price) VALUES 301->200:(0.45);
INSERT EDGE supply(price) VALUES 301->201:(1.12);
```

To find which store's carrots Jinh bought

```
> GO FROM 100 OVER bought where bought._dst==200 YIELD bought.store as store
```

To find how many groceries that "Angela" likes at "Alice's"

```
> GO FROM 101 OVER bought WHERE bought.store = "Alice's"
```

Basically, the design of data model is as much a business concern (i.e., what do you want to query).