# GraphDB: Node as a property of a relationship

Tags: graph-databases

I am trying to analyze graphDB as an alternative to RDBMS for a problem domain. Here is the analogy of a problem I am trying to solve.

**P:Michael** and **P:Angela** **r:like_to_eat** **G:Apple** and **G:Bread**. **G:Apple** and **G:Bread** are **r:available_in** **S:Walmart** and **S:Whole Foods**.
So far it's straightforward. Here is an image that I think best expresses the graph.

[image: Graph database]

The problem is when I try to specify that Angela likes Apples from Whole Foods and Bread from Walmart. And Michael likes to eat Apples from Walmart and Bread from Whole Foods. How can I represent something like that in a graph? It sounds like I need the concept of a hypergraph to be able to solve this problem, but I have also heard that any hypergraph problem can be solved with property graph too. Can this be solved using standard graph solutions like Neo4j or CosmosDB? Can someone please help me with this

Comment: I removed the product-specific tags, as this is a fairly generic graph question. Also, I believe you'll find that any graph database will support something along the lines of what you're trying to create, but with different solutions. I'd focus on a specific question about a specific database engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can "reify" the 3-way relationship (between `Person`, `Grocery`, and `Store`) in a `Preference` node (say), resulting in a data model like this:

[image]

In neo4j, you can use this Cypher query to represent "Angela likes Apples from Whole Foods and Bread from Walmart":

```
MERGE (angela:Person {name: 'Angela'})
MERGE (apple:Grocery {name: 'Apple'})
MERGE (bread:Grocery {name: 'Bread'})
MERGE (wf:Store {name: 'Whole Foods'})
MERGE (wm:Store {name: 'Walmart'})
CREATE
  (angela)-[:LIKES]->(pref1:Preference),
  (pref1)-[:ITEM]->(apple),
  (pref1)-[:AT_STORE]->(wf),
  (angela)-[:LIKES]->(pref2:Preference),
  (pref2)-[:ITEM]->(bread),
  (pref2)-[:AT_STORE]->(wm)
```

Comment: That makes sense @cybersam. It's almost like tweaking the data model a little bit to ensure that there's only 2 vertices for an edge. Thank you.

Comment: cybersam: What is your opinion on @venegr's suggestion below? I feel like modeling the graph in that way makes things easier, but I am not sure which approach would do better performance wise.

Comment: In neo4j, storing a `nodeId` in a relationship is not generally recommended, since you'd need to do more work to lookup the referenced node. Also, going in the opposite direction (e.g., trying to find everyone who likes a particular store) would require more work as well.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to represent "Whole Foods" from "Angela likes Apples from Whole Foods" as a property of the edge "likes to eat", which becomes a real "property graph". Here is the data model:

[image]

In Nebula Graph (which is a graph database slution), you can use the following nGQL query for modelling：

```
// Define the schema
create tag person(name string)
create tag grocery(name string)
create tag store(name string)
create edge likes(storeID int)
create edge sells()

// Insert the vertices
INSERT VERTEX person(name) VALUES 100:("Michael");
INSERT VERTEX person(name) VALUES 101:("Angela");
INSERT VERTEX grocery(name) VALUES 200:("Apple");
INSERT VERTEX grocery(name) VALUES 201:("Bread");
INSERT VERTEX store(name) VALUES 300:("Walmart");
INSERT VERTEX store(name) VALUES 301:("Whole Foods");


// Insert the edges
INSERT EDGE likes(storeID) VALUES 101->200:(301);
INSERT EDGE likes(storeID) VALUES 101->201:(300);
INSERT EDGE sells() VALUES 300->200:();
INSERT EDGE sells() VALUES 300->201:();
INSERT EDGE sells() VALUES 301->200:();
INSERT EDGE sells() VALUES 301->201:();
```

To find which store's apples Angela likes

```
> GO FROM 101 OVER likes where likes._dst==200 YIELD likes.storeID as storeID | FETCH PROP ON store $-.storeID
```

To find how many groceries that Angela likes at Walmart

```
> GO FROM 101 OVER likes WHERE likes.storeID = 300
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: For this approach, do you know how the performance is impacted when i want to query on the properties of the edge/vertex?

Comment: @MichaelScott If you want to fetch the properties of a specific node or edge, it is O(1). Nebula Graph adopts the KV store. For both vertices and edges, the properties are the value part. Refer to the storage design https://github.com/vesoft-inc/nebula/blob/master/docs/manual-EN/1.overview/3.design-and-architecture/2.storage-design.md

If you don't have a specific node or edge, e.g. to find the groceries where the price is higher than 1,  you can create an index for this property. https://docs.nebula-graph.io/manual-EN/2.query-language/4.statement-syntax/1.data-definition-statements/

Comment: The reason why nodeID is not recommended to use as a property is that nodeID is a default internal property and would be reassigned once deleted. In Nebula Graph, nodeID is generated by users, which is why there's no problem using nodeID as an edge property. To find everyone who likes a particular store, use reverse query "go from 300 over sells yield sells._dst as groceries | go from $-.groceries over likes reversely yield likes._dst". The total complexity is o(m) + o(m*k). In Nebula Graph, for a single node, both the incoming and outgoing edges are stored on the same host with the node.